# parsing live streaming tweets with streamR

Tags: r, twitter

I'm trying to listen to a live twitter feed with streamR::filterStream(), parse those feeds with streamR::parseTweets(), and then print all the new tweets every second to the console screen. So far I have two files. The first is:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(streamR)

#load in RData file that contains the ROAuth object called cred
load("PATH_TO_CREDENTIALS_RData_FILE")
registerTwitterOAuth(cred)
filterStream(file="goog_tweets.json", track="goog", timeout=3600, oauth=cred)
```

and the second, which calls the first, is this:

```
library(streamR)

system("R CMD BATCH /home/yourname/twitter/public_listener.R", wait = F)

tweets.df <- parseTweets("goog_tweets.json")
while(TRUE){
  newtweets <- parseTweets("goog_tweets.json", verbose = "FALSE")
  if(nrow(newtweets) > nrow(tweets.df)){
    diff <- nrow(newtweets) - nrow(tweets.df)
    seq <- 1:diff
    print(newtweets[seq,]$text)
  }
  tweets.df <- newtweets
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

How do I make the second script "recognize" when the listener has timed out? How could I do this "better"? The while loop will otherwise just run forever.